# What is the difference between registering an authenticationprovider with HttpSecurity vs AuthenticationManagerBuilder in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter offers two overrides as follows:

`protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`

and

`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)`

Both `HttpSecurity` and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` offer registration for authenticationProviders. Is there any difference between registering my providers with one vs the other?

I'm also using Spring boot 2.1 with `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)` to turn off their autoconfig completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/)

> The main strategy interface for authentication is
>   `AuthenticationManager` [...]
>
> The most commonly used implementation of `AuthenticationManager` is
>   `ProviderManager`, which delegates to a chain of
>   `AuthenticationProvider` instances. An `AuthenticationProvider` is a
>   bit like an `AuthenticationManager` [...]
>
> A `ProviderManager` can support multiple different authentication
>   mechanisms in the same application by delegating to a chain of
>   `AuthenticationProviders`. If a `ProviderManager` doesn’t recognise a
>   particular `Authentication` instance type it will be skipped.
>
> A `ProviderManager` has an optional parent, which it can consult if
>   all providers return null. If the parent is not available then a null
>   `Authentication` results in an `AuthenticationException`.

[image]

Generally speaking `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` provides configuration for `HttpSecurity` apart from `Filter`'s configuration (like `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `LogoutFilter` etc.) it's also creates and configures (adding `AuthenticationProvider`s and parent `AuthenticationManager`) `AuthenticationManager`s in `HttpSecurity` by using `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will create only one `AuthenticationManager` for `HttpSecurity`. However `AuthenticationManager` has its own `AuthenticationProviders` and its own optional parent `AuthenticationProvider`. When you are doing `http.authenticationProvider(...)` you are adding new  `AuthenticationProvider` to the `AuthenticationManager` which belong to that `http`. By using `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` you are configuring `AuthenticationManager` which is the parent of the `AuthenticationManager` which belongs to that particular `HttpSecurity`.

Spring is providing default configuration for the parent of that particular `AuthenticationManager`, but by using `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` you are rejecting spring's configuration in favour of your (auth).