# Spring boot security - inMemoryAuthentication not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Here is my security configuration code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (
        prePostEnabled=true
    )
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("chandra").password("{noop}1234").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/addItem","/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getAllItems").hasRole("USER")
                .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

But while compiling spring is still generating the password for me.

```
Using generated security password: 49f04bde-ac1f-4e30-870b-ba0dd93d50f3
```

I checked whether the configuration is being loaded or not by print statements and found the security config is loading. Is there any change I should make to make it work with the given user ids and passwords.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to log in with given user?

Comment: See for understanding provider managers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404327/what-is-the-difference-between-registering-an-authenticationprovider-with-httpse

Comment: yes in post man i tried and form is being loaded, so I removed .and.formLogin() and tried again with my credentials ('chandra', '1234') but got 403 forbidden.@Andrew Sasha

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue now. Has there been an accepted answer or solution to this question?

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829952/7550229) you should set password encoding

Answer (score 0):

Just a default hint about plain text passwords, you can imagine, what comes next. :-)

Anyway for testing purposes you could define a no operation password encoder like this in your `@Configuration` class:

To make your prepended `noop`working, be sure to expose the following bean:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

> For further information, please consult the respective [chapter in the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#pe-dpe).
>   As an alternative you could provide the good old password manager itself:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

[…]

@Bean
public NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```