# Spring Security - Does overriding WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) affect the global application?

Tags: java, spring-security

In a Spring Secuity / Boot application I have multiple *@Configuration* annotated Configurations that extend *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*. 
In one of these specific configurations, I want to protect a specific URL with basic auth. I do that by overriding *configure(final HttpSecurity)* and using *antMatcher("myURL")* onto the *HttpSecurity* object, followed by the usual authorization-chain and *httpBasic()*.

But configuring basic auth in spring also requires your configuration to override *configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)*, where you configure an authentication-mechanism, as I understand. In my case, that is a simple *inMemoryAuthentication()*, with user and password of my choice. 
Now, I know that some of the other configurations in the project configure the rest of the urls with a way more complex authentication-mechanism, which implement's SSO. I am not entirely sure if my configuration, which messes with the *AuthenticationManagerBuilder*, interferes with these other mechanisms in any way?

My expectation is that, because in *configure(final HttpSecurity)* I use *antMatcher("myURL")*, this configuration will create a SecurityFilterChain that has my specific *inMemoryAuthentication()* logic (somewhere deep in a spring filter that handles basic auth) and that this chain will only be used for the requests matching "myURL" pattern. I expect other filters-chains that are created by other other existing configurations and their more complex authentication mechanisms to be unaffected by my new configuration. My new *inMemoryAuthentication* should never play a role there. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between registering an authenticationprovider with HttpSecurity vs AuthenticationManagerBuilder in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404327/what-is-the-difference-between-registering-an-authenticationprovider-with-httpse)

Comment: Uh, my head swirls from reading that. I will give it an intensive read to check if that answers my question - thanks for the link!